# How would I answer this using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

> You decided that you would give a shot at riding a unicycle while
>   balancing weights on both your hands. To make sure that you don't
>   fall, you want the weights in your hands to balance out as much as
>   possible (i.e. the difference between the sum of the weights in either
>   of your hands must be as small as possible). Given the weights you
>   have, determine the smallest difference in weight between your left
>   and right hands.
>
> Sample Input: 1 10 6
>
> Sample Output: 3

Also, you don't have to use all the weights, but you can't use 0 weights. I'm thinking that a recursive function would be the best way to solve this.

By the way, this isn't my homework or anything, it's a question on a past Dwite contest.

Comment: Based on your rules, the sample output is **wrong**. Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: This is a reformulation of the bin-packing problem, or the knapsack problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PHP is a little rusty, but something like this should work:

```
$left = 0; $right = 0;
for_each($input as $value) {
  if ($left < $right) {
    $left += $value;
  } else {
    $right += $value;
  }
}
$answer = abs( $left - $right );
```

Comment: Just realized this algorithm works for the sample inputs, but breaks if the inputs are different.